# Simplest, fastest way to get treeview item, other methods didnt work for me

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

Theres already posts about getting treeview item and they don't apply to me, my XAML is constructed differently, my treeview is wrapped in buttons, so when I click any of the treeview items, I want 'messagebox.show(selected treeview item path) okay? is that easy to understand? other methods I googled didn't work for me because I already tried them I'd have to re-work my code to get it to work but I don't want that, here's XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="FolderView"   ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Background="#FF3D3C3C" Margin="0,0,285.667,-0.333">


        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}">

                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>



        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:item}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.ClickCommand}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding}">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Type,
                                    Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}" Width="20" Margin="3"></Image>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
              </Button>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    </TreeView>
```

here's button click:

```
public static RoutedUICommand ClickCommand = new RoutedUICommand("ClickCommand", "ClickCommend", typeof(MainWindow));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new DirectoryStructureViewModel();




        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ClickCommand, OnClickCommand, OnCanClickCommand));

        var i11 = new item() { Name = "aaaa aaaa" };
        var i12 = new item() { Name = "bbbb bbbb" };
        var i21 = new item() { Name = "cccc cccc" };
        var i22 = new item() { Name = "dddd dddd" };
        var i0 = new item() { Name = "I1", Children = new List<item>() { i11, i12 } };
        var i1 = new item() { Name = "I1", Children = new List<item>() { i21, i22 } };
        this.FolderView.ItemsSource = new List<item>() { i0, i1 };

    }
    private void OnCanClickCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void OnClickCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((item)e.Parameter).Name);
    }
```

error: 'cannot resolve the symbol 'item'

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: @Ramin I don't know, I just want a message box with the item I chose...

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedItem` property should return the bound item, so you should be able to do:

```
var object = this.FolderView.SelectedItem as YourType;
if(object != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(object.Name);
}
```

Just substitute `YourType` for whatever the type you have bound in your TreeView.
As a side note you can use the `DataType="YourType"` property in your template's XAML which will throw compiler errors if you try to bind a property not in `YourType`.

Comment: didn't work, invite me to a chatroom so I can show you more code

Answer (score 0):

You should use Commands. This example must help you:

**c# code:**

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ClickCommand, OnClickCommand, OnCanClickCommand));

        var i11 = new Item() { Name = "aaaa aaaa" };
        var i12 = new Item() { Name = "bbbb bbbb" };
        var i21 = new Item() { Name = "cccc cccc" };
        var i22 = new Item() { Name = "dddd dddd" };
        var i0 = new Item() { Name = "I1", Children = new List<Item>() { i11, i12 } };
        var i1 = new Item() { Name = "I1", Children = new List<Item>() { i21, i22 } };
        tv.ItemsSource = new List<Item>() { i0, i1 };

    }

    private void OnCanClickCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void OnClickCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(((Item)e.Parameter).Name);
    } 

    public static RoutedUICommand ClickCommand = new RoutedUICommand("ClickCommand", "ClickCommend", typeof(MainWindow));


public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Children { get; set; }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
  <TreeView Name="tv" >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <Button Command="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.ClickCommand}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    <StackPanel> 
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: I am getting an error on 'Item' it's underlined with red, "cannot resolve symbol 'item'"

Comment: This example works. "item" with "i" and not "I" ? (Capital letter)

Comment: Note that c# is case sensitive. It means that "item" is different from "Item"

Comment: Please update your question and give your entire code, or give the complete exception text

Comment: here you go @Ramin

Comment: Sorry, I did not give you the Item class. I updated the answer. You might want to change the Item to item

Comment: 'Cannot resolve symbol 'Item''  in XAML: DataType="{x:Type local:Item}", however, I made it work by replacing it with: local:MainWindow and It works, one last thing tho, how do I re-work it so that it will display my treeview's actual items, what it displays in your answer is 'aaaa aaaa',etc.

Comment: I invited you to 'Treeview WPF' with another one of my accounts, this one has 8 reputation and cant go to chatrooms, accept my invite

Comment: I you did not set xlmns part, remove this part: DataType="{x:Type local:Item}" and it will still work.